# Firebase for a Real-time browser-based MMO

Tags: javascript, html, http, websocket, firebase

I just started using Firebase and I have only positive things to say setup and development with the JavaScript SDK.

Now my question is basically how the "Caps/Limits" works for the Free Tier.. I'm developing a Realtime interactive app that sends constant updates back and forward to the Firebase Database whenever a User move their mouse on a simple webpage. The only data being sent is the position of the mouse (X and Y). Even tho this Data isn't much being sent, it's starting to add it when sending it everytime the mouse position changes, and I have only tested this for a few persons at a time, think about how it would add up if hundreds of people was connected at a time.

Is the 10 GB Limit for the whole month or per. day? I see the Analytics panel says something about Last 24 hours but also Last 30 days.. Kinda confused..

Also, the way I'm sending Data back and forward all the time, is that the most efficient way to do it?

Long term plan for this project:

- Have hundreds of users at a time on the page, sending requests every time their mouse moves.
- Possible additions for the users to have a global paint canvas to paint together.
- And more options.

Think of it as a MMO but no where near the thoursands or late hundreds yet.

Thanks!
- Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transfer cap for the Free tier is 10 GB *per month*. That should be much more data than what you'll need, at least for now.

The real concern is the number of concurrent connections allowed. At the Free and Spark tiers, you are allowed a maximum of 100 concurrent connections. That means only 100 people can play your game at once.

Comment: The thing is, I tested with just a couple of users, after 5-10 minutes, we used up about 10 MB. Think about if we had like 10-20 or 30+, 24/7 online. That 10 GB would be used pretty quickly, no?

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen You can make optimizations. For example, rather than sending data on every mouseMove event, you could implement a timer that caps it at 30 times per second. For server->client data transfer, you will definitely want to cap the rate. Also if you can, don't have the server send *everything*. Only send the data that the client cares about. For example, if certain players aren't visible on my screen, I don't care about what they're doing. No need to transfer unnecessary data.

Comment: For now though, I would focus less on optimizations and more on the game itself. You can always optimize later as your game grows in popularity.

Comment: If you are sending mouse moves from each player to all other players, you've created a high frequency, quadratic bandwidth sink and will indeed quickly run out of your quota. Consider whether each mouse move is relevant to the gameplay. There are probably easy ways to reduce the amount of data that you send. This will not only mean that you can get further within the free tier, but also ensure your game remains scalable as more users play simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and tricks guys. I realize now that Optimization is the best way to do this, and it will definitely help in every way possible. If only Firebase had a Development Tier that could be used for Development, instead of having to actually also think about optimizations right of the bat..